# Getting name from another activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Ok, so i created one activity "areas" where theres a grid view of buttons and a textview on it so you can see the name of the area on the button.
when you click the button it takes you to the "tables" activity where you see actually the same + the number of the table (area name + number of the table), but when i click on area the application crashes because it won't get the name of the area in the table's activity.

I know it's confusing i tried my best with my explanation, I put here both adapters, one for areas and second for tables, in the shortest way, please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

**Area's adapter:**

```
public ArrayList<Area> areas;

public static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public MyAreaAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Area> areas) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.areas = areas;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public MyAreaAdapter(Activity_Table activity_zone){
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagebutton_layout, null);
    }

        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        TextView areaName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.areaName);

    areaName.setText(areas.get(position).getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

**and this is Table's adapter:**

```
    ArrayList<Area> areas;
ArrayList<Table> tables;

public static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public MyTableAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Table> tables) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.tables = tables;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public MyTableAdapter(Activity_Table activity_table){
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;


    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview_table_layout, null);
    }

    ImageView tableImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableImageView);
    TextView tableName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableName);

    tableName.setText(areas.get(position).getName() + " " + areas.get(position).getNumOFTables());

    return convertView;
}
```

Error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
```

this is the line it crashes:

```
TableName.setText(areas.get(position).getName() + " " + areas.get(position).getNumOFTables());
```

**this is the class that invokes my table adapter:**

```
GridView gridView;
ArrayList<Table> tables;
ImageView imageView;
MyTableAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity__table);

    Intent startIntent = getIntent();
    String numTables = startIntent.getStringExtra("numTables");

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);

    OrdersDBAdapter.OrdersDBHelper ordersDBHelper = new OrdersDBAdapter.OrdersDBHelper(Activity_Table.this);
    tables = new ArrayList<Table>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(numTables); i++) {
        tables.add(new Table());
    }        
    adapter = new MyTableAdapter(Activity_Table.this, tables);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyOrderMainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

I added this piece of code to my adapter, with the intent:

```
   public MyTableAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Table> tables, String area_name, String numTables) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.tables = tables;
        this.area_name = area_name;
        this.numTables = numTables;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
```

And I get this Error:

> Error:(43, 19) error: no suitable constructor found for MyTableAdapter(Activity_Table,ArrayList)
>   constructor MyTableAdapter.MyTableAdapter(Context,ArrayList,String,String) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   constructor MyTableAdapter.MyTableAdapter(Activity_Table) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: where your arrayList areas is initialzed?And where your calling the adapter class? You are getting this exception because, your array list is empty?Post the class where you have initialized and invoked the adapters.

Comment: @Ritesh I posted it please check it out

Comment: okay i have posted the piece of code, where you were storing an empty object? Can you also post the code where you are initializing area?

Answer (score 1):

Your app crashes because you're trying to retrieve data from the `areas` ArrayList without instantiating it. Therefore there is no data for the app to retrieve, hence the error.

Make sure your `areas` ArrayList has valid data, for instance by supplying your Adapter with a copy of your `areas` list in its constructor:

```
public MyTableAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Table> tables, ArrayList<Area> areas) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.tables = tables;
    this.areas = areas;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: This is already done, i didn't post it but i already had it in my adapter.

Comment: Do you still have the same error? If you changed your adapter like you said it should work, or you should get a different error.

Comment: Error:(42, 19) error: no suitable constructor found for MyTableAdapter(Activity_Table,ArrayList<Table>)
constructor MyTableAdapter.MyTableAdapter(Context,ArrayList<Table>,ArrayList<Area>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor MyTableAdapter.MyTableAdapter(Activity_Table) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this part of code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(numTables); i++) {
        //What are you adding here.. an empty table object?
        tables.add(new Table());
    }        
    adapter = new MyTableAdapter(Activity_Table.this, tables);
```

Comment: This is the loop for counting the number of the tables. I posted more code with the error i get.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted your full code, I assume you are using two different activities. One uses `MyAreaAdapter` and the other uses `MyTableAdapter`, so let's call them `MyAreaActivity` and `MyTableActivity`. With this, I understand you really don't need all areas in `MyTableActivity`. I think you should pass the area name and number of tables in the intent used to start `MyTableActivity` from `MyAreaActivity`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyTableActivity.class);
i.putExtra("area_name", area.getName());
i.putExtra("area_tables", area.getNumOFTables());
startActivity(i);
```

Then, in `MyTableActivity`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String area_name = intent.getExtras().getString("area_name");
int area_tables = intent.getExtras().getInt("area_tables");
```

And pass it to `MyTableAdapter`:

```
String area_name;
int area_tables

public MyTableAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Table> tables, String area_name, int area_tables) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.tables = tables;
    this.area_name = area_name;
this.area_tables = area_tables;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;


    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imageview_table_layout, null);
    }

    ImageView tableImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableImageView);
    TextView tableName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableName);

    tableName.setText(area_name + " " + area_tables);

    return convertView;
}
```

If you need more information from the area, you could pass the whole object using `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.

If this is not your problem, please give us more details and post your updated code. Otherwise, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: I get this error: Error:(43, 19) error: no suitable constructor found for MyTableAdapter(Activity_Table,ArrayList<Table>)
constructor MyTableAdapter.MyTableAdapter(Context,ArrayList<Table>,String,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor MyTableAdapter.MyTableAdapter(Activity_Table) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)